# Transformed elements with generated content/pseudo element don't adhere to z-index

Tags: css, z-index, pseudo-element, css-transforms

Basically, if you look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/edelman/c83gy/) you'll see that I have an element with a transform applied to it that has generated content. The `:after` element is supposed to appear behind the `div` but it's not. No amount of `!important`-ing is having any effect.

**How can I get the pseudo-element to appear behind the `div`?**

I don't care about IE 8 or below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although this is strange, and often unwanted behavior, it is also expected. Essentially, transforming an element creates a new stacking context, which in the case of pseudo-elements, means they can no longer sit behind the element they are based on.

See this article for more information: https://daneden.me/2012/04/22/css-transforms-and-z-index/

Currently, the only way to resolve this would be to create the new stacking context on the parent element (i.e. create a wrapper element and transform that). Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/joshnh/GzWnb/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="box"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper {
    -moz-transform: rotate(10deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
    transform: rotate(10deg);
}
#box{
    width: 200px; 
    height: 200px;
    left: 100px;
    top: 100px;

    background:blue; 
    position: absolute;
    &:after{
        content: "";
        width: 100px;
        background: orange;
        height: 100px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 120px;
        top: 120px;
        z-index: -2!important;
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah i saw that article when i was researching, but i was hoping that maybe it's been taken care of. i know it's "expected", but it's hardly expected. I understand it should create a "new" stacking context, but that stacking context should be wholly based on pre-existing stacking contexts. Or, if not, there should be a way for the user to modify said new stacking context.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you. I don't fully understand why that decision was made and wish there was a way around it.

Keep in mind that setting z-index on the base element (as you have currently done) will do the same thing, as will setting an opacity less than 1.

Comment: wish i could upvote this again. had this same problem and googled it, ended up here :) maybe i should learn my lessons

Comment: Broken link for the article, available on the [web archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20130424214806/http://daneden.me/2012/04/css-transforms-and-z-index/)